# Oracle rds db instance and it's replica in cross region using terraform script

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating oracle RDS db instance and cross region replica (using terraform main.tf) for the same but i am getting below error while applying the script; it seems in subnet resource group something went wrong, please help me to resolve below error. I have called subnet group in main instance block and same in replica block also but still getting below error please help me to resolve this error

```
│ Error: creating RDS DB Subnet Group (sank): InvalidParameterValue: Some input subnets in :[subnet- 
  023e4c0e518c1db07, subnet-0f7b2a6481f8aeb9e] are invalid.
│       status code: 400, request id: 864eeebd-ad79-4362-963b-d47ad50fc9e2   with aws_db_subnet_group.sank, on main1.tf line 6, in resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "sank":
│    6: resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "sank" {

│ Error: creating RDS DB Subnet Group (sank1): InvalidParameterValue: Some input subnets in :    
 [subnet-03acb5d6d1071d2c5, subnet-05c2bdeaeea13d741] are invalid.
│       status code: 400, request id: 457fa973-b4c3-4776-b003-dc0de397105f
│   with aws_db_subnet_group.sank1,
│   on main1.tf line 41, in resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "sank1":
│   41: resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "sank1" {
│
```

#terraform main.tf#

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us-east-1"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "sank" {
  name       = "sank"
  subnet_ids = ["subnet-023e4c0e518c1db07", "subnet-0f7b2a6481f8aeb9e"]

  tags = {
    Name = "Sank"
  }
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "primary" {
  allocated_storage    = 100
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  engine               = "oracle-ee"
  engine_version       = "19.0.0.0.ru-2023-07.rur-2023-07.r1"
  instance_class       = "db.m4.large"
  username             = "dbadmin"
  password             = "yourpassword"
  parameter_group_name = "default.oracle-19"

  db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.sank.name
  vpc_security_group_ids  = ["sg-0afeaf6497b1f3364"]
  license_model           = "bring-your-own-license"

  multi_az = true

  tags = {
    Name = "oracle-db-primary"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us-west-1"
  region = "us-west-1"
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "sank1" {
  name       = "sank1"
  subnet_ids = ["subnet-03acb5d6d1071d2c5", "subnet-05c2bdeaeea13d741"]

  tags = {
    Name = "Sank1"
  }
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
  provider             = aws.us-west-1
  allocated_storage    = 100
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  engine               = "oracle-ee"
  engine_version       = "19.0.0.0.ru-2023-07.rur-2023-07.r1"
  instance_class       = "db.m4.large"
  username             = "dbadmin"
  password             = "yourpassword"
 
  parameter_group_name     = "default.oracle-19"
  db_subnet_group_name     = aws_db_subnet_group.sank1.name
  vpc_security_group_ids   = ["sg-034dc2c037d48ebbc"]

  license_model        = "bring-your-own-license"

  multi_az = true

  tags = {
    Name = "oracle-db-replica-cross-region"
  }
}
```

I am creating oracle rds db instance and cross region replica (using terraform main.tf) for the same but i am getting below error while applying the script; it seems in subnet resource froup something went wrong, please help me to resolve below error. I have called subnet group in main instance block and same in replica block also but still getting below error please help me to resolve this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your previous question, you are not using the aliased providers properly. For every resource that needs to belong to an aliased provider, you need to specify which of the aliased providers it is going to use:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us-east-1"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "sank" {
  provider   = aws.us-east-1
  name       = "sank"
  subnet_ids = ["subnet-023e4c0e518c1db07", "subnet-0f7b2a6481f8aeb9e"]

  tags = {
    Name = "Sank"
  }
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "primary" {
  provider             = aws.us-east-1
  allocated_storage    = 100
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  engine               = "oracle-ee"
  engine_version       = "19.0.0.0.ru-2023-07.rur-2023-07.r1"
  instance_class       = "db.m4.large"
  username             = "dbadmin"
  password             = "yourpassword"
  parameter_group_name = "default.oracle-19"

  db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.sank.name
  vpc_security_group_ids  = ["sg-0afeaf6497b1f3364"]
  license_model           = "bring-your-own-license"

  multi_az = true

  tags = {
    Name = "oracle-db-primary"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us-west-1"
  region = "us-west-1"
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "sank1" {
  provider   = aws.us-west-1
  name       = "sank1"
  subnet_ids = ["subnet-03acb5d6d1071d2c5", "subnet-05c2bdeaeea13d741"]

  tags = {
    Name = "Sank1"
  }
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
  provider             = aws.us-west-1
  allocated_storage    = 100
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  engine               = "oracle-ee"
  engine_version       = "19.0.0.0.ru-2023-07.rur-2023-07.r1"
  instance_class       = "db.m4.large"
  username             = "dbadmin"
  password             = "yourpassword"
 
  parameter_group_name     = "default.oracle-19"
  db_subnet_group_name     = aws_db_subnet_group.sank1.name
  vpc_security_group_ids   = ["sg-034dc2c037d48ebbc"]

  license_model        = "bring-your-own-license"

  multi_az = true

  tags = {
    Name = "oracle-db-replica-cross-region"
  }
}
```

Please make sure you understand how [aliased providers](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration#alias-multiple-provider-configurations) work before using them.

Comment: i used updated code now it is saying combination error, please can you give me suitable combination for free tier a/c;
Error: creating RDS DB Instance (): InvalidParameterCombination: RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination: DBInstanceClass=db.m4.large, Engine=oracle-ee,EngineVersion=19.0.0.0.ru-2023-07.rur-2023-07.r1, LicenseModel=bring-your-own-license. For supported combinations of instance class and database engine version, see the documentation.
status code: 400,

Comment: That's a different question altogether.

Comment: Hi The above script is working fine, but what i am missing is i want to create replica of same oracle db instance from east region to west region, in my script it is creating new instance. please help me to achieve that using identifiers?

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is not a free coding service. Please make sure you read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/649837) before asking new questions.